# Python tkinter value passed to query sqlLite3 is not working

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to python. I was making a small gui using tkinter to get id and name from user and pass it to sqlLiteDb to fetch the result. but every time I am getting garbage value in response.

Below is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry('300x200') 
window.title("Welcome to GUI app")

lbl = Label(window, text="Name")

lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
tst=Entry(window,width=10)
tst.grid(column=1, row=0)
tst.focus()
lbl1= Label(window, text="Id")

lbl1.grid(column=0, row=1)
tst1=Entry(window,width=10)
tst1.grid(column=1, row=1)

# Method to Fetch the data from db
def getData(id,empname):
    import sqlite3 as sq
    con=sq.connect('C:\\SqlLiteDB\\testsql.db')
    cr=con.cursor()
    res=cr.execute("select inc from emp where eid=? and ename=?",(id,empname))
    return res

# Method binded on click        
def buttonClick():
    result=getData(tst.get(), tst1.get())
    output=result
    lbl2.configure(text=output)
btn = Button(window, text="Check Increment",command=buttonClick)

btn.grid(column=3, row=3)
lbl2 = Label(window, text="")
lbl2.grid(column=0, row=4)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `tst` is the Entry for the name and `tst1` is the Entry for the id right? You pass `(tst.get(), tst1.get())` and accept that as (id,empname). This seems to be the wrong way around.

Comment: but the issue that i faced during debug was that the select query which is fetching the data and storing is returning garbage value too in normal python class when i am trying to print(res)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are likely experiencing this because you are not fetching what you are executing. You ought to use the `.fetchall()` method.
2. Always use control variable for tkinter widgets like `entry`, they give you more control over the type of data passed. From your code, `tst` seems to be used to hold `ids`, which I believe should be integers, but as your code is, you will always get `str` type returned unless you use control variables:

   ```
   def getData(id,empname):
       import sqlite3 as sq
       con=sq.connect('C:\\SqlLiteDB\\testsql.db')
       cr=con.cursor()
       cr.execute("select inc from emp where eid=? and ename=?",(id,empname))
       res=cr.fetchall()
       return res
   ```